# Windows - How to redirect all console output to text file? The console program is called by another software that I can't control

Tags: windows, console, batch, ms-dos

It is a pretty complicated issue (at least for me).

GUI software at a given moment, calls console software, which outputs something to console and quits. I'd like to save those results to a text file, but I can't call the console software myself.

Is there anyway to globally record all console outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  You'll have to contact the software vendor to have them implement that within their software.

If it's a console app you should be able to run it manually outside of the software, you just need to figure out what it's called and what the parameters are for it.